# Error: Cannot assign requested address [::1]:27017 when accessing MongoDB from WebAPI in Docker on local machine

Tags: c#, docker

I am encountering an error when my WebAPI project attempts to access MongoDB. Both of these applications are in the same container network, and this setup is on my local machine.

The error message from the WebApi container log is:

```
Cannot assign requested address [::1]:27017
```

When launching the WebAPI project from Visual Studio, the Dockerized MongoDB is accessible, and the WebAPI project can receive data.

MongoDB settings - appsettings.json:

```
 "MongoDbSettings": {
   "Host": "localhost",
   "Port": "27017"
 },
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - EyalShop

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    restart: always
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672   
      - 15672:15672 #for management
    volumes:
      - rabbitmqdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    networks:
     - EyalShop

  products:
    image: productapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Products/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5143:80
      - 7270:443
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - EyalShop
    volumes:
      - ./cert.pem:/app/cert 

networks:
  EyalShop:

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
  rabbitmqdata:
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Products/Products.csproj", "Products/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Products/./Products.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Products"
RUN dotnet build "./Products.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./Products.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Products.dll"]
```

Comment: You do not have exposed port 27017 in other containers, just on your local machine. You can use docker links.

Answer (score 1):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - EyalShop

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    restart: always
    container_name: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - 5672:5672   
      - 15672:15672 #for management
    volumes:
      - rabbitmqdata:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    networks:
     - EyalShop

  products:
    image: productapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Products/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5143:80
      - 7270:443
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - EyalShop
    volumes:
      - ./cert.pem:/app/cert 

networks:
  EyalShop:

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
  rabbitmqdata:
```

So now in your products service ‘mongo’ will be link (host) to mongo service

```
"MongoDbSettings": {
  "Host": "mongo",
  "Port": "27017"
},
```